# No aparece el Fee en mi cuenta

Tags: mercadopago

Creo que tengo configurado todo correctamente, pero cuando ejecuto la llamada al servicio, descuenta el FEE pero no se donde se aplica ya que en mi cuenta no están. Este es el código PHP, me falta algo?

```
$preferences = array('items' => array( array('id' => $listing['listing_id'],
                                            'title' => $listing['title'],
                                            'description' => $listing['description'],
                                            'quantity'  => (int) $transaction['quantity'],
                                            'category_id' => $listing['category_id'],
                                            'unit_price' => (float) ($listing['price'] + $transaction['shipping_cost']),
                                            'currency_id' => $listing['currency_code'],
                                            'picture_url' => $listing['images'][0]['url_170x135'])),
                    'marketplace_fee'   => 0.6,
                    'order_id'          => $transaction['order_id'] ? $transaction['order_id'] : '',
                    'external_reference'=> $transaction['transaction_id_decoded'].(isset($transaction['receipt_id']) ? "-{$transaction['receipt_id']}" : ''),
                    'payer'             => array(   'name' => $this->CI->session->userdata('first_name'),
                                                    'surname' => $this->CI->session->userdata('last_name'),
                                                    'email' => $this->CI->session->userdata('email')),
                    'back_urls'         => array(   'success' => site_url(array($this->CI->lang->line('site_url_cart_process_payment'), 'success')),
                                                    'failure' => site_url(array($this->CI->lang->line('site_url_cart'))),
                                                    'pending' => site_url(array($this->CI->lang->line('site_url_cart_process_payment'), 'pending')),
                                                    'payment_methods' => array( 'excluded_payment_types' =>  array( array('id' => 'ticket'), array('id' => 'atm'))))
            );

log_message('debug', "create_checkout:".json_encode($preferences));

curl_setopt_array($this->ch, array( CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => TRUE,
                                    CURLOPT_HEADER          => FALSE,
                                    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT  => 3,
                                    CURLOPT_CAINFO          => dirname(__FILE__)."/cacert.pem",
                                    CURLOPT_POST            => TRUE,
                                    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => json_encode($preferences),
                                    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => array("Accept: application/json", "Content-Type: application/json"),
                                    CURLOPT_URL             => "https://api.mercadolibre.com/checkout/preferences?access_token={$access_token}"));

$create_preference = json_decode(curl_exec($this->ch));
```

Comment: ¿Tenés declarado ésto al principio?
require_once ('mercadopago.php');
$mp = new MP('SELLER_AT');

Comment: Hola! gracias por la respuesta. Por lo que veo, en principio no, no lo tengo dentro de esa funcionalidad, es decir para otras funcionalidades si lo tengo, pero no para esta. Podrías referenciarme a la documentación exacta de armado de pedidos de compra y toma de fee ?? ya que la documentación que vi yo simplemente armando el JSON como lo armo yo debería funcionar.